# 4 Node Cassandra Cluster, Each Has 50.00%

Tags: cassandra

I am running 4 node on a Cassandra cluster built in Windows platform. When I run

nodetool -h localhost ring

command on seed node, I see each nodes in up status, normal state and own **50.00%** which I expect to see **25.00%**. Is this normal to see the each node owns the 50.00%?

Here is the configuration of each node;

**1. Node**

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
initial_token: -9223372036854775808
listen_address: [IP Addres of the machine]
seeds: "[IP Addres of the seed machine (1. Node)]"
```

**2. Node**

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
initial_token: -4611686018427387904
listen_address: [IP Addres of the machine]
seeds: "[IP Addres of the seed machine (1. Node)]"
```

**3. Node**

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
initial_token: 0
listen_address: [IP Addres of the machine]
seeds: "[IP Addres of the seed machine (1. Node)]"
```

**4. Node**

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
initial_token: 4611686018427387904
listen_address: [IP Addres of the machine]
seeds: "[IP Addres of the seed machine (1. Node)]"
```

Initial Tokens calculated by using this formula; (2^64 / 4) * [NodeIndex] - 2^63

Cassandra 1.2.1 installed in each node. Any idea about the 50.00% value for each node?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really say how much each node owns until you setup a replication factor and create a keyspace. Create a KS with replication_factor=1 and each node will own 25%.

Answer (score 0):

Is your replication factor 2?

That would explain it - you have your data twice in the ring.

Comment: I've just configured nodes and wait for node loads to be equal to create keyspaces by choosing a Replication Strategy. So, there are only system keyspaces for now.